# How can I reliably and accurately identify the passive voice in writing or speech?

Tags: grammar, terminology, passive-voice

How can I *reliably* and *accurately* identify the passive voice in writing or speech? I'm not interested in advice about whether or not to use it yet... I just want to know for sure what it is, so that I don't look as stupid as [these people](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2524).

Comment: You really need to change the chosen answer on this post, because, unfortunately, it contains some completely incorrect information. It says that passives cannot contain a direct object. This is clearly incorrect. In ***Mary was given a ball***, the noun phrase ***a ball*** is a direct object. In the corresponding active voice sentence *Mary* would be the indirect object. The Direct Object remains the same when Mary is made the subject of the sentence. :)

Comment: Oh, looks like Nohat's done a fix on the answer. Good stuff! :)

Comment: In some cases, you can't. _The window was broken_ may or may not be a passive construction. In _The window was broken by the golf ball_ it certainly is and in _The window was broken, we noticed_ it certainly isn't.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If a clause has all of the following, then it is in the passive voice:

- A form of an auxiliary verb (usually *be* or *get*)
- The past participle of a **transitive** verb
- No direct object
- The subject of the verb phrase is the entity undergoing an action or having its state changed

Example: *The documents were printed*.

Optionally, the agent is expressed in a prepositional phrase with *by*: *The documents were printed by the printer*.

There are some exceptions; though, generally speaking, if a given clause meets all the above conditions, then it is certainly passive voice. The Wikipedia article about the [English passive voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice) has a pretty complete coverage, detailing all cases of English passive voice, but the major exceptions are these:

- A passive clause may have a direct object in the case of [ditransitive verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb); when the *indirect* object is promoted to subject, the direct object remains. (*Someone gave Mary the documents* becomes *Mary was given the documents*.)
- In [concealed passives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice#Additional_passive_constructions), the verb form is a gerund-participle and has no auxiliary. (*Your document needs printing*)
- In [bare passives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice#Additional_passive_constructions), the auxiliary is missing, but these clauses can only be used as modifiers (***With the document printed***, Mary could hand in her paper), or in special syntactic constructs like newspaper headlines (*Document printed by printer*).
- Some related forms, the [passival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice#Middle_voice_and_passival) (*The document is printing*) and [middle voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice#Middle_voice_and_passival) (*These documents print well*), may be considered to be kinds of passive voice.

Comment: There is a small class of exceptions to the “no direct object” condition, if I’m not mistaken: [ditransitive verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb).  For instance, the active sentence *Alice gave Bob some books* has two passive forms, *Some books were given to Bob by Alice* and *Bob was given some books by Alice*.  This second form has a direct object.  (The two passive forms correspond to the two objects of *gave*: *books*, which is certainly direct, and *Bob*, who is arguably indirect and optionally could be given a pronoun and moved to the end of the sentence.)

Comment: (Note that in the original sentence, one can argue that there is an elided proposition and *books* is the only direct object of *gave*; but in the sentence *Bob was given some books [by Alice]*, it is unambiguous that *Bob* is now the subject and *books* the object, since the verb is *was* not *were*.)

Comment: In addition, the passive voice can exist apart from clauses, in which case no auxiliary verb is needed.

Comment: Oh man. Nohat, ya gotta fix this post. I know you know better. (Other threads are getting directed here.)

Comment: That the fourth (semantic) point is important is shown by the fact that 'The kitchen window was broken' is in the passive voice if the fourth rule is satisfied (when say 'by the golf ball' comes next) but is a copular construction if it does not apply (when say 'When we got there, we found that' precedes). 'I am finished' may even be a perfect construction, meaning 'I've done'.

Comment: Thanks for the fix! :) Though a little explanation might help too ... :-)

Comment: Er, is it actually necessary for a passive clause to contain an auxiliary verb? What about bare passives? (Also, do grammars, in general, consider "get" to be an auxiliary verb?) And that last bullet: *"The subject of the verb phrase is the entity undergoing an action or having its state changed"*, might that be considered to be an overgeneralization?

Comment: *"The past participle of a transitive verb"* <== Er, I guess that's somewhat reasonable, if you don't want to consider or include concealed passives (e.g. "The lawn needs mowing").

Comment: @F.E. OK, OK, I have added more details about the exceptions.

Comment: This answer is faulty. *The documents were printed* is not necessarily a passive construction.

Comment: *The documents were printed, not hand-written*. *I took him printed documents, not hand-written documents*. These are adjectival participles.

Comment: @Araucaria *"Many years ago, there was killed on this field one mean ugly over-weight T-Rex."* <== Is that passive voice, do ya thunk? I mean, w.r.t. the criteria in this answer post? :D . . . (Hey, it's a legitimate break, I hope, from me pragmatics stuff and all.)

Comment: @F.E. "*Many years ago, there was killed on this field one mean ugly over-weight T-Rex.*" <--- No, this isn't a passive. But interestingly "*There are believed to be hundreds of shipwrecks surrounding Long Point*" would seem to be a passive where the direct object of the matrix clause has become the subject of the passive version. Not sure that's related though ...

Comment: @Araucaria So there's the active *"Someone believes there to be hundreds of shipwrecks surrounding Long Point"*, hmm, okay, I guess. But then there's the active *"Many years ago, someone killed there on this field one mean ugly over-weight T-Rex"*, er, now I'm confused, why isn't my earlier example the passive of that? :D

Comment: Passive or no: A: *I am surprised that Mary has not done the dishes*. B: *I am surprised by Mary's not having done the dishes.* C: *I am surprised with you, Mary, because  you've not done the dishes.* D: *I am surprised with you, Mary.*

Comment: @Araucaria Yanno, since I no longer (er, for the moment anyway) consider the concealed passive to be syntactically a passive, it makes it much easier for me to identify passives. A passive construction involves a past-participle verb form that's used in a passive interpretation (vs a perfect interpretation). Of course, this now shifts the identifying problem to figuring out whether a past-participle is being used for a passive or a perfect interpretation, and to figuring out whether the past-participle shaped word is a verb or some other thing, such as an adjective. :D

Comment: @F.e. So a "get" passive would be a passive then?

Comment: @Araucaria Yup (because it involves a bare passive--it is the bare passive that makes a passive be a passive). Though, I'd thought maybe you would've been using a comment for something else, maybe something concerning passives that are stative or something like that, w.r.t. verbal passives vs adjectival passives.

Comment: @f.e. So causatives with verb PCs are mostly passives?

Comment: @f.e. Are you sure you've made that *easier*?

Comment: I just don't believe "the car needs washing" is any kind of passive at all, no matter what Wikipedia says. The car needs something (direct object). What does it need? Washing (gerund). So: Subject noun, active verb, object noun. Maybe the car needs a good washing. Subject noun, verb, object NP (indef article + modifier + noun). How could anyone call that passive?

Comment: @Araucaria It'll make the discussion a lot easier if you could provide an example and your interpretation of what is going on in it and what you're assuming my position would be. Otherwise, I'm just guessing as to what you might be talking about. (And consider that I'm also currently going through SPE and constantly having to decipher what he's trying to say. That is no fun.)

Comment: @F.E. Sorry, I can't remember what SPE is?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Well, it's a bit more complicated than this, but it's basically because: The car needs itself to be washed.

Comment: @F.E. I don't have a position! I have a confusion! I would prefer to regard the passive proper as a construction with some form of  *BE* and a past participle and thereby exclude, for example, constructions with *get* or *have* (which I definitely don't regard as passives) or participles post-modifying noun phrases. I think the "passive meaning" is difficult (though no doubt possible). But I can't see how it's going to be pulled of given sentences such as "They are believed to be ...."

Comment: @F.E. When I say "I would prefer", what I mean is "I would prefer it if that was the case", not "I think that's what passives are" :D

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24645/discussion-on-answer-by-nohat-how-can-i-reliably-and-accurately-identify-the-pas).

Answer (score 13):

*Passive voice* is a construction where the object of a transitive verb is moved into the subject position, and the subject is optionally moved into a prepositional phrase. In English, the passive can always be identified by ***to be* + past participle**. Some examples:

> Active: Kim hits the ball.
> Passive: The ball is hit by Kim.
>
> Active: Grandma baked a cake.
> Passive: The cake was baked by Grandma.
>
> Active: Mr. Henry bought the painting for six million dollars.
> Passive: The painting was bought for six million dollars.

Note the following:

- All of these sentences contain a form of the verb *to be* followed immediately by a past participle. Without that telltale, it's not a passive sentence.
- The prepositional phrase with *by* is optional, as in the last sentence. However, a sentence that identifies the actor with a phrase beginning with *by* is usually passive.

Now, to clear up some common misconceptions.

*Intransitive verbs* are never passive, even if the subject of the verb isn't doing anything. For example, **none of the following are passive**:

> The boy fell down.
>
> Six buildings burned to the ground.
>
> The cake is baking.

All of these sentences have *intransitive verbs*, which are verbs that do not take an object. The fact that the subject of the verb isn't really "active" in any of these cases does not make these examples of "passive voice". All of the previous are in fact *active voice*.

Second, passive voice has hardly anything to do with the "focus" of the sentence. For example, the following is not passive:

> We all watched John make a brilliant save.

The "focus" of the action here is John, but that's irrelevant to the question of active voice and passive voice. The main verb *watched* is in the active voice, and *John* is the object of *watched*. The passive version of this sentence would be:

> John was watched making a brilliant save by all of us.

(Which is an extremely awkward sentence.)

Finally, there are two other constructions sometimes misidentified as passive because they share some syntactic features with the passive voice, but which emphatically are *not* passive.

The first is the *progressive*, which consists of ***to be* + present participle**. (The present participle always ends in *-ing*.) For example, **none of the following are passive**:

> Kim is hitting the ball.
>
> Grandma was baking a cake.

Although these contain a form of *to be*, they aren't passive since they don't contain the past participle.

The second is the *perfect*, which consists of ***to have* + past participle**. For example, **none of the following are passive**:

> Kim has hit the ball.
>
> Grandma had baked a cake.

Although these contain the past participle, they aren't passive since the participle doesn't follow a form of *to be*.

Comment: In *let's eat the cake made by auntie Val*, "baked" is passive. No form of *to be* is necessary.

Comment: @Cerberus, you're right. The word *made* (or *baked*) is a passive participle, but the clause that it's in is in the active voice.

Comment: True. Different voices can be embedded in one another. Be glad that we are no Ancient Greeks, who had three voices: active, medium, and passive...

Comment: Passive or no: A: *I am surprised that Mary has not done the dishes*. B: *I am surprised by Mary's not having done the dishes.* C: *I am surprised with you, Mary, because  you've not done the dishes.* D: *I am surprised with you, Mary.*

Answer (score 8):

Grammar Girl had a good podcast on this very topic recently: ["Active Voice Versus Passive Voice"](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/active-voice-versus-passive-voice.aspx)

She had a really good definition for passive voice:

> **What is Passive Voice?**
>   In passive voice, the target of the
>   action gets promoted to the subject
>   position. Instead of saying, "Steve
>   loves Amy," I would say, "Amy is loved
>   by Steve." The subject of the sentence
>   becomes Amy, but she isn't doing
>   anything. Rather, she is just the
>   recipient of Steve's love. The focus
>   of the sentence has changed from Steve
>   to Amy.

I really like her debunking the myth that a sentence is automatically in passive voice if the verb is a "to be" verb. For example the following sentence is definitely in active voice despite what Strunk & White think.

> I am holding a pen.

Comment: On what planet is "am holding" a "to be" verb?

Comment: "Am" is clearly a "to be" verb. "Holding" is a gerund. I'm not sure what you are suggesting with that comment.

Comment: *holding* is a participle here

Comment: When you passivise a sentence the focus of the sentence changes so that it is NOT on the new subject. That's the whole point of a passive.

Comment: @Araucaria No the focus is on the new subject. The old subject has been defocused and is completely optional. What else would the focus be on?

Comment: @curiousdannii No, we usually passivise a sentence to make the subject link back to old information in the previous sentence. The new info, which is the focus of the sentence then comes at the end of the current sentence. We don't like to put new interesting info at the beginning it goes at the end. So we often passivise to put the emphasis on the action in the verb phrase, or on the agent, the person doing the action - who will appear at the *END* of the sentence, it they're mentioned at all.

Comment: @curiousdannii Compare "***I've been studying the Mona Lisa. The Mona Lisa was painted by Leonardo Da Vinci***" and "***I've been studying the Mona Lisa. Leonardo Da Vinci painted the Mona Lisa***". The first is better because the new info is at the end and the focus goes on this new info! :)

Comment: Strunk and White is garbage; don't believe anything they say about grammar. Some of their writing advice is harmless, although not exactly helpful, either: "Avoid needless words". I think the problem with all the answers here is that they assume there **is** a "passive voice" in English, instead of a host of syntactic rules producing different kinds of constructions, some of which are "passive-like", at least to some people. More Latinate thinking again, based on a false presupposition. Latin **did** have a passive voice, and it was inflected on almost every verb; English doesn't.

Comment: @JohnLawler do you have any resources with which to further explore the issue? Second, based on your statement that there is not a passive voice in English, what do you think English teachers should do, stop presenting this concept? What should we replace it with? I'm seriously interested. Or perhaps you would like to actually answer the question.

Comment: @JohnLawler Passive or no: A: *I am surprised that Mary has not done the dishes*. B: *I am surprised by Mary's not having done the dishes.* C: *I am surprised with you, Mary, because  you've not done the dishes.* D: *I am surprised with you, Mary.*

Comment: @pazzo: There is a passive construction in English. It is a fairly complex rule that modifies grammatical relations, changes inflection, and adds another auxiliary verb. It is not, however, a "voice", which is a technical term that applies to Latin, but not to English. As for the examples, those are complex sentences with several clauses; passive can only apply to one clause at a time, and -- depending on the clauses -- some, all, or none of them can be passive. So the question is meaningless; it's not sentences that can be passive, but clauses.

Comment: @pazzo: I think English teachers should be taught English grammar before they commence teaching English. Most aren't. As to what to substitute for "the passive voice", I have no idea whatsoever. What are you looking for -- a new name? If it's bullshit, ignore it.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think the distinctive between passive constructions and a passive voice is instructive. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnLawler D: *I am surprised with you, Mary* has only one clause. Is this a passive construction?

Comment: No. A passive would use _by_ and not _with_. This is the predicate adjective. And by the way what is the vocative contributing to the example? It has nothing to do with passive construction.

Answer (score 5):

[Mass insanity over passive UFOs continues](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2524), the *Language Log* article linked to in the OP, is one of a series by Professor Pullum, co-author of the monumental *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, in which Pullum derides comments in the "news media and political blogosphere" that misattribute the term *passive* to any construction in which the speaker or writer appears to be attempting to conceal the agent.

Thus, for example, the grammatically-clueless political commentator detects the attempt to avoid agency in both *There were mistakes in the planning of the operation* and *Mistakes were made in the planning of the operation*, and assumes that the term *passive* can be applied to the former because it is correctly applied to the latter.

Of course, there is no reason why the term *passive* should not evolve to denote any utterance that obfuscates the agent, but for the purpose of this answer I shall stick to a discussion of what grammarians understand by the term.

Before we can identify something, we have to define it. Since dictionaries are the usual place to look for definitions, it is helpful to cite from the entry for *passive* in the *Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar* (ODEG), p294-296:

> A construction (verb phrase, clause, or sentence) in which the
> referent of the grammatical subject typically
> 'undergoes','experiences' or 'receives' the action of the verb (i.e.
> is its patient).
>
> ...
>
> In formal terms, a passive construction
> contains a form of the passive auxiliary *be* (or *get*) combined with a
> past participle.

So to test whether any given construction is a canonical passive construction, we need to ask:

- Does it contain a form of the *be* or *get* auxiliary together with a past participle?
- Does the grammatical subject undergo, experience or receive the action of the verb?

In most cases these tests will be sufficient to determine whether a construction is passive or not. For example, the first test will immediately rule out the *There were mistakes* construction since it does not contain a past participle. Conversely, *Mistakes were made* contains a form of the *be* auxiliary together with the past participle, and the grammatical subject, *mistakes*, can be said to undergo the action of the verb, *to make*, so it is passive.

Of course, it is the nature of language that there will be edge or non-canonical cases. @Nohat's answer includes some examples such as bare passives, and links to Wikipedia's [article on the passive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice), which in my opinion is a good overview of the topic.

The Wikipedia article also deals with the issue that appears to be  most exercising the setter of the bounty for this question - namely, how to classify constructions such as *I am surprised by you, Mary*.

For a discussion of this point, it is useful to cite the ODEG once more:

> Some passive sentences are ambiguous. Thus *The opera house was
> finished in 1980*, out of context, is most likely to have an actional
> meaning referring to the building activity, namely 'the building work
> was completed in 1980'. This is called an **actional passive**. But it
> could also have a statal meaning, i.e. 'the building was in a finished
> state in 1980'. This is called a **statal passive**. In an actional
> passive the string *be + past participal* clearly forms a passive
> construction, whereas in a statal passive *be* is a copular verb and the
> *-ed/en* form is an adjective. The statal passive is sometimes called *pseudo-passive* or *adjectival passive*.

So, finally, how do we determine whether constructions such as *I am surprised by you* are actional passives or statal passives? Well, a reliable classification of decontextualised constructions is not possible since we don't have access to the speaker's communicative intention. But we can speculate, in which case it is useful to return to the second test:

> Does the grammatical subject undergo, experience or receive the action
> of the verb?

If the speaker means something like *Everyday I am surprised by you creeping up behind me while doing the dishes*, then we have an actional passive because the *I* is receiving the action of the verb *to surprise*.

If, conversely, the speaker is making a general statement that he is in a constant state of surprise caused by Mary and the various things she does and says, then we have a statal passive.

---

Since writing the *Mass insanity over passive UFOs* on *Language Log*, Pullum has added another article, whose explicit intention is to teach the grammatically clueless what constitutes a passive construction, and what doesn't: [The passive in English](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2922).

Comment: Passive or no: A: *I was surprised when I got home last night*. B: *The window was broken at the exact moment that Guy broke it.*

Comment: @pazzo. Based on the ODEG definitions _"I was surprised when I got home last night"_ could be the _statal_ (_adjectival, pseudo_) passive (_I was already in a state of surprise when I got home last night_) or the _actional_ passive (_I was surprised by a bird landing on my car when I got home last night_). I don't understand your second example: Is "_at the exact moment that Guy broke it_" part of your example sentence or an explanation of the circumstances?

Comment: It's part of the sentence. C: *I was happy*.

Comment: There's a long discussion of _adjectival passives_ and how to test for them in the CGEL on p1436-1440. You might want to ask a separate question about them.

Comment: Oh, and this answer holds so much promise. Second, I've no access to the book.

Comment: Still not sure I get it. Is it: _I was happy that the window was broken at the exact moment that Guy broke it?_

Comment: Oh, sorry. No they are separate: B: *The window was broken at the exact moment that Guy broke it*. C: *I was happy*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24501/discussion-between-shoe-and-pazzo).

Comment: +501 for **a reliable classification of decontextualised constructions is not possible since we don't have access to the speaker's communicative intention.** which was the point I was trying to make with the bounty, i.e., there is no reliable and accurate test.

Comment: In many instances you can distinguish a passive with an action or process sense from an adjectival construction with a stative sense.  However, it doesn't follow from this that a construction with a stative sense must be adjectival and not a passive.  Not only does it not follow, it isn't even true.  Consider the passive "Ohio is bordered on the north by Lake Erie."  It's stative -- there is no agent and progressive aspect is not allowed.  It's not adjectival, since the adverb modifier "very" is not permitted: *"Ohio is very bordered ...".

Answer (score 3):

The English passive structure to be + past participle is theoretically ambiguous. It can describe a passive action (1 The bridge was destroyed) or it can describe a state/condition (2 The bridge was destroyed).

You decide which of the two possibilities is meant either by context or logical judgement.

English can avoid this ambiguity by adding a passive agent (3 The bridge was destroyed by soldiers) or by using the continuous form (4 The bridge was being destroyed when we arrived) or the get-passive (5 The bridge got destroyed).

Comment: Passive or no: A: *I am surprised that Mary has not done the dishes*. B: *I am surprised by Mary's not having done the dishes.* C: *I am surprised with you, Mary, because  you've not done the dishes.* D: *I am surprised with you, Mary.*

Comment: No sentence contains a passive.

Comment: What if *D* said *I am surprised by you, Mary*?

Comment: Does a passive make sense?

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms:

The boy **kicked** the ball. Active. The ball **was kicked** by the boy. Passive.

There are lots of related constructions, but you will need to consult a good grammar such as the "Cambridge Grammar of English" if you need a detailed analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a form of the verb "to be" followed by the past participle of an *active, transitive* verb.   Next, determine if the participle is describing the action or the subject.  Many adjectives use the same form as the past participle when they are describing a *state of being.*  In the passive voice, the verb "to be" must be acting as an auxiliary (helper) verb and not as a copula (linking verb).  Using the cake example, the word "baked" can be either an adjective, where "the cake was baked" describes the state of the cake, or as a passive verb, where "was baked" describes the action that was done to the cake by an unidentified agent.  You have to look at the context of the sentence. Most of the time, if you can add the phrase "by someone or something" to the *main clause* without changing the meaning of the sentence, you are using the passive voice.  (Note that in the sentence "We ate the cake baked by Grandma," the main clause is "we ate the cake" and "baked by Grandma" is a defining relative clause describing the cake.  See http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/defining-relative-clauses/ for more information on defining relative clauses.)

There are several instances where a writer might choose to use the passive voice.  Some examples are: The actor(s) is unknown, but implied.  The actor(s) is irrelevant.  You want to be vague about who is responsible, often to avoid placing blame (or giving credit).  You want to emphasize the recipient of the action by making it the subject of your sentence.  You are writing in a scientific genre that traditionally relies on passive voice (less common).  (http://www.writing.utoronto.ca/advice/style-and-editing/passive-voice)

Comment: Passive or no: A: *I am surprised that Mary has not done the dishes*. B: *I am surprised by Mary's not having done the dishes.* C: *I am surprised with you, Mary, because  you've not done the dishes.* D: *I am surprised with you, Mary.*

Comment: "Surprised" in each of these examples appears to be an adjective, describing the emotional state of the subject, except in sentence B.  B appears to be passive, but I would reword it to say "I am surprised by Mary's failure to do the dishes" for clarity.

Comment: What if *D* said *I am surprised by you, Mary*?

Comment: If there is a clear-cut difference in grammaticality between the following, it suggests that "surprised with" (or "surprised at") is adjectival, but "surprised by" is a passive.  "I am very surprised at you." / *"I am very surprised by you."  This is because "very" cannot modify verbs, and the passive participle is a verb.  (Unfortunately, I find the facts here unclear.)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest rule that I can suggest here is that the subject of the sentence is not 'Actively' doing something. He/She/It is 'Passive' i.e. it is being acted upon. the subject here is the recipient of action, rather than the doer.

e.g.

"The child was struck by the car."
" The fruit was eaten"

Here,The child was acted upon by the car. Likewise for the fruit here.

Comment: Counterexample: the bill became law.  The bill isn't actively doing anything, but the grammatical construct is active voice. In contrast to, say, "the bill was signed into law."

Answer (score 0):

Meaning is not always a clear indicator; but grammatically it should be easy to spot: look out for a form of 'to be' followed by a past tense form, such as

The ball WAS KICKED.

The questions IS ANSWERED in the next section.

The film HAS BEEN SHOWN before.

And if there is an actor present, it would be in a BY-phrase, but that can be omitted (as in the examples here).

Answer (score 0):

A passive construction occurs when you make the object of an action into the subject of a sentence. That is, whoever or whatever is performing the action is not the grammatical subject of the sentence.

[credit UNC](http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/passive-voice/)

Answer (score 0):

If you can add "by zombies" to the end of the phrase, and it makes sense, the phrase is passive.

Ex:

**John was eaten** *(by zombies)*. Thus, this is the passive tense.

**Zombies ate John** *(by zombies)*. That doesn't seem to make sense, so this is in the active tense.

Answer (score -2):

I think following articles will be helpful to you:

> 1. [Passive Voice - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_voice)
> 2. [English Passive Voice - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice)
> 3. [Passive Voice Self-Tests](http://www2.gsu.edu/~accerl/passive/PA.html)

Comment: Please summarise these links - link only answers aren't allowed here.

Answer (score -2):

When I'm teaching passive vs. active voice, I use this rule of thumb:

Look at the sentence. Can you find the person or thing doing the action? If you can't find it in the sentence, that's usually the first tip that the sentence is passive. And if you can find it - is the thing doing the action coming before or after the verb? If it's before the verb - active. If it's after the verb - passive.

The popcorn was made. (passive - the person making popcorn isn't in the sentence)

The popcorn was made by me. (passive - "me" comes after the verb, "was made")

I made the popcorn. (active - "I" comes before "made")

There are of course exceptions, but this sends to be simple and easy.

Comment: So `"That's correct," said I` is passive because "I" comes after "said"? Nonsense.

Comment: "There is always an easy solution to every human problem -- neat, plausible, and wrong." H.L.Mencken

Comment: And yet, for students studying passive voice (at lower levels of fluency), this piece of advice will help them enormously, since subject inversions (outside question structures and 'so/neither do I') are only studied at higher levels.