# Use of "to catch up"

Tags: phrases

In the context of knowledge of something, the phrase "to catch up" is apparently being used in both active and passive ways. For example:

> I have to catch up on the latest news.
>
> Can you catch me up on the latest news?

To me, this seems not logical if I think about catching up requiring some effort on the part of the person that is not up to date. Instead, I would prefer

> Can you help me catch up on the latest news.

To me, the usage gets more confusing if catching up refers to physical distance, for example, a cyclist who wants to catch up with another. For me,

> Rider A was caught up by rider B

would mean that A was in front but than B caught up with him, rather than B helped A catch up with other riders in front.

My question is:

**What is the meaning of the cycling example for native speakers?**

PS: updated in response to comments. It seems that I was not actually talking about "passive voice". Apologies to @TRomano for the changes after their answer.

Comment: I think, some speakers are more likely to say that someone *was brought up to speed* when referring to news/gossip/latest developments

Comment: Can you refine the question you are asking.

Comment: “He was caught up by her [on the latest news]” is not a meaningful sentence to me. If I hadn’t had the context of the immediately preceding example, I wouldn’t have had the faintest idea what it was supposed to mean. Can you clarify where you’ve come across this usage? I’m guessing it’s a dialectal feature of sorts; at least I’ve never heard or seen it before.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You might be right. I changed the example.

Comment: The passive equivalent of "she earned her promotion" would be " "her promotion was earned by her". The reason is that, in  reality, she did the earning and the payment was what was earned, changing from the active to the passive voice does not change the relationship between the two parties. The same thing happens when we say "John visited Susan" or "Susan was visited by John". Whichever way we say it it was still John's finger on Susan's doorbell.

Comment: You SHOULD NOT change the question *after* a user has spent time answering the original question with its original examples. It is disrespectful to the user who answered, their answer now appears strange and unrelated

Comment: You need to revise the passive voice, the 2nd example is not passive. See https://english.stackexchange.com/a/552/44619

Comment: @Mari-LouA You are of course right, sorry about that and the changes to the question. I clearly should have thought about this more before posting.

Answer (score 1):

> He was **caught up *to*** by her.†

He had been ahead of her but she narrowed the distance between them and managed to come "alongside" him (literally or figuratively).  The verb **catch up** in its meaning where it does not take a direct object, and used here in the passive voice.

> She caught up to him.

Same underlying meaning as above, verb not taking a direct object, here in the active voice.

> He was caught up by her.

Here **catch up** is used in its transitive meaning and in the passive voice: she brought him "up to speed" on the matter. She gave him the information he lacked. She tutored him or briefed him.

---

†Compare:

> The chair was **sat down *on*** (by someone)
>
> Having got off to a good start he was briefly in the lead but was soon **caught up *to*** by the other runners.

Do you see how the preposition is carried over when the verb not taking a direct object is used in a passive construction?

> Someone sat down **on** the chair.
>
> The chair was sat down **on** by someone.
>
> The baby played **with** the rattle.
>
> The rattle was played **with** by the baby.

I suppose it's possible to see the verbs there as **sit (down) on** and **play with** and then go on to assert that they *do* take a direct object.  But however you want to analyze it, the preposition comes along for the ride in passive constructions using verbs like this.